# R progranmming 4.1.1 automatically uninstalled by windows 10

Tags: r

For some reason the R programming 4.1.1 is automatically uninstalled by Windows 10 and it is replaced by R 4.2.2.

I tried to keep both 4.1.1 and 4.2.2 at the same time but for some reason the 4.1.1 is kept being uninstalled by Windows.

If I run the R.Net application in VB.Net 2017 with R 4.2.2, I get an error in the following line:
`REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables()`

The error message is:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I added strings in the SetEnvironmentVariables such as
`Dim rhome As String = "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2"`
`Dim rpath As String = "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64"`
`REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rhome, rpath)`
`Dim Rstat As REngine = REngine.GetInstance()`

but it keeps giving me the following error message in the next line (Dim Rstat As REngine = REngine.GetInstance()`): 'This 32-bit process failed to load the library R.dll. Native error message is 'The handle is invalid'

Can anyone help me by

1. How to prevent windows patch automatically uninstall R 4.1.1.
2. Work a solution with R 4.2.2 to prevent getting the above error messages.

Thanks

If I run the R.Net application in VB.Net 2017 with R 4.2.2, I get an error in the following line:
`REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables()`

The error message is:'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I added strings in the SetEnvironmentVariables such as
`Dim rhome As String = "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2"`
`Dim rpath As String = "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.2\bin\x64"`
`REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables(rhome, rpath)`
`Dim Rstat As REngine = REngine.GetInstance()`

but it keeps giving me the following error message in the next line (Dim Rstat As REngine = REngine.GetInstance()`): 'This 32-bit process failed to load the library R.dll. Native error message is 'The handle is invalid'

Can anyone help me by

1. How to prevent windows patch automatically uninstall R 4.1.1.
2. Work a solution with R 4.2.2 to prevent getting the above error messages.

Thanks